# Python - Combinging Multiple Lists with "zip" that have duplicate key values

Tags: python

I understand dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, makes good sense...

Here's what I have.

```
a = ['02', '02', '03']
b = ['01', '02', '01']
c = ['10G', '10G', '10G']
d = ['08', '07', '09']

newDict = dict(zip(a, zip(b, c, d)))
print(newDict)
```

This code produces--

```
{'03': ('01', '10G', '09'), '02': ('02', '10G', '07')}
```

I'm missing a set of data since '02' is duplicated. and Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

It would be great to combine a + b as the dictionary key to output--

```
{'0201': ('10G', '08'),'0202': ('10G', '07'), '0301': ('10G', '09')}
```

How is that done?

I tried 
newDict = dict(zip(a + b, zip(c, d)))
but it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a dictionary comprehension. We also don't need the nested `zip`

```
{x+y: (z, w) for x, y, z, w in zip(a, b, c, d)}
# {'0201': ('10G', '08'), '0202': ('10G', '07'), '0301': ('10G', '09')}
```

Comment: wow, thank you! Works like a charm.  Taking me a little processing power to understand (new to coding here).  Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to concatenate every leading character even if it is a unique value in its row. Instead, you can use recursion to find the proper level that will garner a unique key:

```
import itertools, collections
a = ['02', '02', '03']
b = ['01', '02', '01']
c = ['10G', '10G', '10G']
d = ['08', '07', '09']
def group_data(_start):
  new_l = [[a, [c for _, *c in b]] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(_start, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
  _d = {}
  for a, b in new_l:
    if len(b) == 1:
      _d[a] = tuple(b[0])
    else:
      _d.update(group_data([[a+i, *c] for [i, *c] in b]))
  return _d

print(group_data(list(zip(a, b, c, d))))
```

Output:

```
{'0201': ('10G', '08'), '0202': ('10G', '07'), '03': ('01', '10G', '09')}
```

Comment: I see what you did there, that's really impressive.  I'm going to be later calling either the key or the values in the list-- it's probably better all the lists have the same quantity.  I'm super new to coding, trying to keep it simple and stupid for now :)  Really appreciate your reply and I'm going to save this snippet, thanks.

Comment: @BennyMcFarley Glad to help!